# Slow initial response time

Tags: django, apache

I have a website that is experiencing some slow initial response time. The site is built with Django, and runs on an Apache2 server on Ubuntu. I have been using the Django Debug Toolbar for debugging and optimization.

When making a request to a user profile page, the browser is 'waiting' for ~800ms and receiving for ~60ms for the initial request. However, the Django Debug Toolbar shows that time spent on the CPU and time spent on SQL queries only adds up to ~425ms.

Chrome devtools:
[image]

Django debug toolbar:

[image]

Even a request to the index page (which has no SQL queries and almost no processing - it just responds with the template) shows ~250ms wait time.

[image]
[image]

I tried temporarily upgrading the VM to a much more powerful CPU, but that did not (noticeably) change this metric.

This leads me to believe that the wait is not due to inefficient code or database latency, but instead due to some Apache or Ubuntu settings.

After the initial response, the other requests to load page resources (js files, images etc) have a much more reasonable wait time of ~20ms.

What could account for the relatively large initial 'waiting' time?
What tools can I use to get a better picture of where that time is going?

Comment: There's a reasonable chance the latency is simply due to initialization / module imports if you are only seeing it on the first request. A good solution is simply to locally make a request whenever you restart Apache (e.g. before you register this instance with your load balancer). Unless you've configured your threads to expire after a certain number of requests, that should be all you need.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I'm not sure I understand your comment entirely. The wait time is there each time the page is refreshed, regardless of whether Apache was restarted or not. After the HTML request (shown in the images above), the next request for the CSS file does not experience this same wait time and this is the same for all files after the HTML request

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem across all three of my stacks (prod, dev, and qa).

Comment: @pizoelectric unfortunately no. I'll be sure to post something once I find an answer

Comment: @Hat I was able to resolve my issue. Your mileage my vary, but here's what I did. I started with the simplest view I could find. I had one in my code base that was a TemplateAsAView which just takes a url and renders an .html doc. Then I started putting print statements in my stack until I could see where the hangup was. Turns out, in my case it was an LDAP server bind event that was firing on every page due to a login_required decorator. Once I knew it was the bind event, one of my developers wrapped it in a caching call. This greatly alleviated my long waiting periods. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same; even when set up with nginx and flup on my local server, I can still see initial latencies up to 2 seconds when even the simplest view comes back, even though the debug toolbar says that very little CPU / DB time were taken.